# With a vsan issue where you cant access vcenter, should you ssh into all machines and power them down prior to restarting esxi host?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vcenter, vmware-vsan

So I have a vsan cluster, 4 esxi hosts all contributing to vsan as well as compute. Vcenter lives in esxi01. Esxi01 is not responding and I cannot open the web gui.

I can still ping every vm and ssh into most. I believe esxi01 is out of file descriptors.

Is it best to ssh into all vms in the environment (linux vms) and shut them down that way since vcenter isnt available or should I reboot esxi01 with everything online so vcenter is semi aware of everything's last state?

Thank you. Wasnt finding much online for this scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please clarify, is it StarWind vSAN https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san or VMware vSAN https://www.vmware.com/products/vsan.html as these two share the same name, but are two very different products under the hood.

For my perspective, I had no issues with StarWind running SDS for VMware vSphere. Can't say much about VMware's. In your case, I would shut down all VMs manually via SSH and then reboot the VMware vCenter. But firstly, I would check backups and might try to run a backup job to have recent ones.

Also, you could try to reboot just vCenter VM. https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1004340